# Programmatically adding Azure components

Tags: api, azure

I'm wondering if it's possible to add, say another network interface to my Azure VM from an external source, such as a custom GUI that my customers can access.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Start here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx

Client Libraries that wrap these APIs are available in many languages.

Resource Manager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/

Comment: The link you included in your answer is for Azure Service Management API which will be deprecated soon. I would request you to edit you answer and include links to Azure Resource Manager API. Thanks!

Comment: Yes please include ARM as well. It seems to be relevant.